# file upload of different maxSizes using multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I want to upload files of mimetype video and image through multer but the size limit for both the files should be different. For image size limit should be 2MB and for video 50MB.So, how do I exactly do this. I tried various things but nothing works.

```
router.post('/addUserPost', function (req, res, next) { 
    upload(req, res, function (err) { 
         if(err)
            { 
               for(var i=0;i<req.files.length;i++){ 
                  if(req.files[i].mimetype.split('/')[0]=='image'){ 
                      maxSize=5*1024*1024; next(); 
                  } 

                  if(req.files[i].mimetype.split('/')[0]=='video'){ 
                       maxSize=50*1024*1024; next(); 
                  } 
                } 
             } else next(); 
     }); 
}, upc.addUserPost);
```

Comment: You can define `maxsize` for image and video and check the mimetype to set the maxsize as same

Comment: We are not seeing any code related your post here, please update your question with code so that people can help you.

Comment: router.post('/addUserPost', function (req, res, next) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
     if(err){
      for(var i=0;i<req.files.length;i++){
       if(req.files[i].mimetype.split('/')[0]=='image'){
        maxSize=5*1024*1024;
        next();
       }
       if(req.files[i].mimetype.split('/')[0]=='video'){
        maxSize=50*1024*1024;
        next();
       }
      }
     }
     else
     next();
    });
}, upc.addUserPost);

Comment: I am not able to edit my post by putting my code in it. It always shows error of "post may contain............"

Comment: what is the issue? you are getting with this code

Comment: its not taking that maxSize and still uploading if the file is greater than that size

Comment: You are not checking the file size anywhere, just uploading the file with given size.so check the size before uploading